# Select Entries Only with Dates Between Two Specified Dates

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a query for a MySQL database that returns entries that have a DateTime between a specified Date range. Is there any way to write something like

`SELECT myField FROM myTable WHERE myDATE IS BETWEEN {DATE-RANGE}`

or something that accomplishes the same purpose?

For what it's worth, I'm using PHP to run this query.

Comment: I suppose MySQL's [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) comparison operator would be a bit too easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than you think with MySQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myDate > '2008-6-22'
AND mydate < '2014-1-10'
```

this will return rows with the date between June 22, 2008 and Jan. 10, 2014.

Comment: Note that `myDate` is `DATETIME`: this will exclude midnight on 2008-06-22 but include the rest of the day.

Comment: This actually ended up being what I used (over BETWEEN) since I ended up having to use 2 date values (start and end).

Answer (score 2):

Google works wonders, the search box on the top right of SO works miracles!!

In any case, you are looking for exactly what you wrote!

```
SELECT myField FROM myTable WHERE myDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-05 23:59:59' ORDER BY myDate
```

Comment: No worries.  But actually, since you mention milliseconds, if one is using MySQL >= 5.6.4, `myDate` may be stored with up to microsecond precision... in which case one would need to go up to `'2014-01-05 23:59:59.999999'`!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IN ... BETWEEN operator or the < <= >= > operators to achieve your goal.

Of course, things get complicated if your date is stored as a varchar, which is a common mistake.